# Для чего нужны переменные в среде командной строки?

Tags: ос

Для чего нужны переменные в среде командной строки?

Comment: Много для чего. Для сокращения строки за счёт содержимого переменной, для создания скриптов, для передачи данных в вызываемые приложения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные среды позволяют обходиться без указания абсолютных путей к директориям. Например, если нам заранее неизвестна буква системного диска, мы всегда можем использовать переменную `%systemdrive%`, возвращающую букву диска, на котором установлена ОС. Также, переменные применяются для оптимизации кода - многократно повторяющемуся параметру (например, разделе реестра) можно назначить короткую переменную и использовать ее.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ есть в самом вопросе - переменная она такая переменная т.е. может меняться
Три типовых примера изменения:

1) Как написали выше - переменные среды. На разных ПК стандартные файлы или папки могут находиться в разных местах, например в ОС Windows переменная среды %WINDIR% указывает на папку, в которую установлена ОС

2) Переменные сеанса - если вам необходимо найти папку текущего пользователя, то в той-же Windows это переменная %UserProfile%, которая в свою очередь, состоит из переменной среды, константы и переменной сеанса: %SystemDrive%\Users{username}

3) Просто переменные - нужны когда нужно что-то поменять - хотите вы пробежать циклом сто раз - не обязательно сто раз запускать команду - переменная счетчика в помощь, хотите использовать результат вычисления cli приложения для следующего вычисления - сделайте его переменной и т.п.